# undefined is not a function arr.filter

Tags: react-native, sqlite, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to filter data in flatlist but this error is showing up:

[image]

this is my code:

```
const [custData, setCustData] = useState([]);
  const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState('');

<FlatList
      data={custData.filter(item => {
        if (searchFilter === '') {
          return item;
        } else if (
          item.partyname
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchFilter.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          return item;
        }
      })}
      keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>{item.partyname}</Text>
      )}
    />
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making changes in `data` of a `FlatList`, make a `useEffect` which will have `custData` as a parameter make changes to it and set the values to your state and render that state.

The code should look like this

```js
const [custData, setCustData] = useState([]);
const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState('');

const toFilterData = async () => {
    return await custData?.filter(item => {
        if (searchFilter === '') {
          return item;
        } else if (
          item.partyname
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchFilter.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          return item;
        }
      });
}

useEffect(() => {
    setSearchFilter(toFilterData());
}, [custData])

<FlatList
      data={searchFilter}
      keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>{item.partyname}</Text>
      )}
    />
```

Do try to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will be helpful in future.

Thanks :)